# ComputerVisionClient or Xamarin Essentials Error - Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined when calling method ReadInStreamAsync

Tags: azure, computer-vision, ocr

So I am capturing a photo and opening a stream using Xamarin.Essentials 1.7 MediaPicker built into Essentials.

When I call the ReadInStreamAsync(stream) method in Computer Vision Client, I get an error and my Xamarin.Forms app breaks inside the method: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'

This is the stream.Name value - '/data/user/0/com.companyname.xamphotoappdemo2/cache/2203693cc04e0be7f4f024d5f9499e13/198fd32db9cc4be38a493325974fa138/d964251252fc4963aca94339d73a8007.jpg'

This is my code:

```
var file = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions 
        { Title = "Please take a photo" });

        if(file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();

            chosenImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

            // 2. Add OCR logic.

            var client = Authenticate(ApiSettings.subscriptionKey, ApiSettings.endpoint);

            var text = await client.ReadInStreamAsync(stream);
            

            //after the request, get the operation location
            string operationLocation = text.OperationLocation;

            //we only need the operation ID, not the whole URL
            const int numberOfCharsInOperationId = 36;
            string operationId = operationLocation.Substring(operationLocation.Length - numberOfCharsInOperationId);

            //Get the ocr read results
            ReadOperationResult results;
            do
            {
                results = await client.GetReadResultAsync(Guid.Parse(operationId));
            }
            while ((results.Status == OperationStatusCodes.Running || results.Status == OperationStatusCodes.NotStarted));

            var readResults = results.AnalyzeResult.ReadResults;

            var expirationDates = from page in readResults
                                  from line in page.Lines
                                  where line.Text.Contains("EXPIRES") && line.Words.Count == 4
                                  select line.Words[3].Text;

            expirationDate.Text = expirationDates.ToString();

            photoPath.Text = file.FullPath;
```

The image is displaying as expected in the XAML Image control and that is reading the image source from the stream, so is this a bug in the ReadInStreamAsync method?